# How should I implement a confusion matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

I know what is a confusion matrix.

Given N classes we have a NxN matrix M where
- each row is one of the classes
- each column is one of the classes

M(X,Y) = number of elements which have been classified in class X and should have classified in class Y (of course if X=Y the classification is correct).

Now I have a set of "compound classes" and a **variable** number of classes

- with "COMPOUND" I mean that one class corresponds to a vector (of **variable** length).
  For example if the class is represented by a 2 element vector,the possible classes will be:

  [0,0]

  [0,1]

  [1,0]

  [1,1]

Mi goal is to define a function with:

- INPUT: a NxM matrix (where N=number of classified elements,M=number of elements of each class) of classified elements , a NxM matrix of expected class for each element.
- OUTPUT: NXN confusion matrix corresponding to input classes

Example of OUTPUT:

```
[1 0 0]
[0 2 0]
[0 1 0]
```

**This matrix is 3x3 matrix.**

This means the the total number of classes is 3 and number of classified elements are 4:

- one element should have been classified in class 1 and has been classified in class 1
- two elements should have been classified in class 2 and have been classified in class 2
- one element should have been classified in class 3 and has been classified in class 2

(it doesn't matter how the elements are composed of.
Let's image the classes may be:

```
[0,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,1]
```

** Example of input matrix (EXPECTEDclasses): **

```
[0,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,1]
```

** Example of input matrix (OBTAINED classes): **

```
[0,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,0,1]   <-- this is the element(line) incorrectly classified
```

How should I do? (the classification is made by a Perceptron or Adaline neuronal network)

Thank you in advance for any hint!

Comment: Give an example of what you want the confusion matrix to look like with your "compound classes"

Comment: And what's the example INPUT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) in the following form: `[Lia,Locb] = ismember(A,B,'rows')`  The second output argument tells you which row of matrix B that each row of matrix A matches.  Use this information to construct the confusion matrix (which is a built-in function in the stats toolbox).

```
classes = [0 0 1;
            1 0 1; 
            1 1 1];
 expected = [0 0 1;
             1 0 1;
             1 0 1;
             1 1 1];
 obtained = [0 0 1;
             1 0 1;
             1 0 1;
             1 0 1];    
>> [~, ex] = ismember(expected, classes,'rows')    
ex =    
     1
     2
     2
     3

>> [~, ob] = ismember(obtained, classes,'rows')    
ob =

     1
     2
     2
     2

>> confusionmat(ex,ob,'order',[1 2 3])    
ans =

     1     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     1     0
```

If you don't have access to `confusionmat`, you can use `accummarray` to do it yourself.

```
num_observations = length(ex);
num_classes = size(classes,1);
accumarray([ex,ob],ones(num_observations,1),[num_classes,num_classes])
```

Comment: thank you for the good solution. But is there any way without using confusionmat?

Comment: thank you again. and what about if "expected" has some different element than "obtained"? For example: in "obtained" there is class which is not expected to exist

Comment: Where do you think it should go in that case? My inclination would be to add an "invalid" class by replacing the zeros in `ob` with a new "class code" and increment `num_classes` to accommodate the extra value. `num_classes = num_classes+1; ob(ob==0)=num_classes;`

Comment: ok,just las question: how should I calculate the number of "not-existent/invalid" classifcations?

Comment: That is something you ought to be able to handle yourself.

Comment: sorry.. I'm missing something. accumarray([ex,ob],ones(num_observations,1),[num_classes,num_classes]) . The confusion matrix is "[ex,ob]"? mmm..maybe I should assign it to a variable: right?

Comment: `cm = accumarray(...` the confusion matrix is the output of accumarray.